# Calculating $\int_{\mathbb{R}^5}\frac{e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}}{1+w^2+s^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz\,dw\,ds$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Calculate the following:
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^5}\frac{e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}}{1+w^2+s^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}w\,\mathrm{d}s$$

I tried to do the following (based on the suggestion below):

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^5}\frac{e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}}{1+w^2+s^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}w\,\mathrm{d}s &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}{e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{1+w^2+s^2}\,\mathrm{d}w\,\mathrm{d}s
\\&=\pi^{3/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+r^2}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\\&=\pi^{3/2}\cdot2\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+r^2)\right)\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}
\\&=\infty
\end{align}

but I'm not sure about it, would appreciate your help:)

Comment: This is correct: integral diverges as $\sim\log r$ at $r\to \infty$

Comment: Correct method & correct result. Even if you didn't know the value of $U=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x^2}dx,$ you could see that $0<U\le \infty$ & therefore your final result holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose the product of a sphere in $x,y,z$ with a circle in $w,s$.  So a 5-D version of a cylinder.
Then break up into $\iiint dxdydz\iint dwds$